# It is possible to add asm to flowcode?

Tags: pic

I have a friend that use it and need to add two lines of asm to calibrate the OSC of a PIC12F675 so need to make a call to the last program address that have a RETLW 0xYY where YY is an hexadecimal value to write the OSC calibration.

In CCS I just do it by using #asm and #endasm like this

```
#asm
call 0x3FF
bsf status_reg,RP0
movwf OSCCAL
bcf status_reg,RP0
#endasm
```

But he says that he get a compilation error by using that code.

Comment: Please provide compiler and error.

Comment: @jolati Is BoostC, and after read the manual a bit and several attemps I finally solved, thanks for the tip about check the compilator.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you can add asm code in C for the major microchip compilers the following way:

```
   {
    _asm
    call 0x3FF
    bsf status_reg,RP0
    movwf OSCCAL
    bcf status_reg,RP0
    _endasm
   }
```

Comment: Is BoostC compiler and don't need the _endasm. The strange is that do not accept hexadecimal when you are referring to a variable, movwf 0x0090 is not accepted but movwf osccal yes.